# How to update all functions in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Is there a way to quickly fill down a column of functions. For example, if I change my function from

```
=3*B2
```

And then fill down so it does it for a lot of rows.

But then change this column to:

```
=10*B2
```

Is there a way to quickly update all my functions in the column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your formula in the first cell. Position you mouse over the bottom-right hand corner of the cell, the cursor which change from a white-cross to a black-cross. Double-click and your range will auto-fill with your new formula.

Answer (score 4):

Drag and Fill Again.

If this is a common occurrence you can used **Named Constants** for the constant value, so you can change it easy.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a copy and replace.

So highlight the cells you want to change, and do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> and replace the value according.

However this might have side effects you might not desire.

For example lets say you want to change 3 to 10, then you might actually change cell B3 to B10, B30 to B100 etc. . .

Your best bet is to make a constant by having all the values represented in another cell.

For exmaple A1 then your formula will look like

```
$A$1 * B1
$A$1 * B2
$A$1 * B3
```

etc.. .

Then you just change A1 and all your forumlas update accordingly.

($ means don't change the cell either column or row after when I do a drag or fill.  In this example A and 1 do not change.)